# Audio is not working after upgrade to ubuntu 15.10 from 15.04

Tags: sound, 15.10

I have been using Ubuntu 15.04 for almost a month now, the audio used to work fine. Until the 15.10 update. Sometimes there was a startup sound, but after the login there is no sound icon in the menu bar. Tried playing a video with `vlc` gives error:

```
 Audio output failed:
The audio device "default" could not be used:
No such file or directory.
```